# Adding option "convert to pdf" to right click?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, context-menu, right-click

I am using windows 7
As shown in attached snapshot,When i right click on any file,a menu/drop down opens. Which does not contain option "convert to pdf"

How can i add this option to right click menu?[image]

Comment: Are you using an up to date version of Adobe Acrobat?  The context option exists in Windows 10, Adobe Acrobat Pro DC.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be: "Why SHOULD it contain this option on the right click menu?".. Did you expect Microsoft to provide converting ANY file to PDF?  That doesn't even make sense.  I want a PDF of my pRoN.zip file..  ?? ..

Comment: If you don't have the entry in the context menu by default, it could be added by modified the registry. But Adobe acrobat does not have any command line options. Still there are tools to do this from command line, and using them the context menu can be added.